# Write into single colorAttachment in one drawcall

Tags: opengl-es, fbo

I created a fbo with two-color attachments i.e., colorAttachment0 and colorAttachment1.

so my question is I want to draw into single colorattachment in one draw call.

in my shader i tried this but not working:

```
if(attachmentVal==0) //I am sending the attachmentVal as uniform
{
outColor = vec4(1,0,0,0);
}
if(attachmentVal==1)
{
outColor2 = vec4(1,1,1,0);
}
```

But it is not working.
so my question is, is it possible to render into a single attachment in a single draw call by controlling the selection of the attachment??

If possible please give me a solution to this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glDrawBuffers()` to select which attachments are active for the current draw.

Comment: `GLenum buffs[] ={GL_COLORATTACHMENT0,GL_COLORATTACHMENT1};   glDrawBuffers(2,buffs);`   //so i  want to control rendering into which of the colorattachments by uniform in fragment shader.  Is it possible??

Comment: Select whichever attachments you want active. The shader can write to both, but if the draw buffer is "NONE" the write just gets dropped.

Comment: so for one draw call, i have to bind the fbo and set the attachment by `glDrawBuffers()` and for the next drawcall again bind the fbo and change the attachment ????

Comment: No, leave the FBO alone - changing that is very expensive. Just use glDrawBuffers() to change which attachments are enabled on a per-draw basis.

Comment: @solidpixes .  you mean , i have to do it like  the below code. ??     `renderLoop()
{
//Draw1

GLenum buffs[] ={GL_COLORATTACHMENT0};   glDrawBuffers(1,buffs);

glDrawArrays();


//Draw2
GLenum buffs[] ={GL_COLORATTACHMENT1};   glDrawBuffers(1,buffs);
glDrawArrays();
}`